# Create Attachment in Azure Project is not working

Tags: azure, azure-devops, attachment

Create Attachment in Azure Project is not working. In start attachments are created. but now create black image on every call with same code and same image.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#examples

**Code sample**

```
$data = fopen("test.png", 'rb');
$size = filesize($file);
$contents = fread($data, $size);
fclose($data);
$encodedData = base64_encode($contents);
        
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/OrganizationName/ProjectId/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=test.png&uploadType=simple&api-version=6.0";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$header = array("Authorization:Basic ".base64_encode($params['username'].":".$params['token']),"Content-Type:application/octet-stream");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
if ($params['request']) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($encodedData));
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

**Response is**

```
stdClass Object
    (
    [id] => f1f55c9e-8f48-4408-90f0-69ebb3c4d0ff
    [url] => https://dev.azure.com/muhammadhaneef0757/749218ab-92a7-4ed1-86d8-738d8c3888e8/_apis/wit/attachments/f1f55c9e-8f48-4408-90f0-69ebb3c4d0ff?fileName=test.png
    )
when i check url in browser there is showing black image
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved Code sample**

```
$data = fopen("test.png", 'rb');
$size = filesize($file);
$contents = fread($data, $size);
fclose($data);
        
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectId}/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=test.png&uploadType=simple&api-version=6.0";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$header = array("Authorization:Basic ".base64_encode($params['username'].":".$params['token']),"Content-Type:application/octet-stream");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $contents);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response = json_decode($response);
```

**Link with workitem**

```
$postRequest = [];
$postRequest[] = ["op"=>"add",
"path"=> ("/relations/-"),
'from' => null,
"value"=> ["rel"=>"AttachedFile",
            "url"=>$response->url
            
            ]
];
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectId}/_apis/wit/workitems/{workitemId}?api-version=6.0";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$header = array("Authorization:Basic ".base64_encode($params['username'].":".$params['token']),"Content-Type:application/json-patch+json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postRequest));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helped you.